# PHP regex with preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to get the vimeo ID of this iframe code, which is my string.

```
$str = '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/34134823?title=0&amp;byline=0" width="900" height="506" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>'
```

I believe the ID part `34134823` can be more or less than 8 characters so I can't use indexes.
I could do it with 2 explodes, one for `http://player.vimeo.com/video/` and than one for the `?` question mark, but I am sure it would be better with a regex, only I am a noob with that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$str = '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/34134823?title=0&amp;byline=0" width="900" height="506" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>';

$stat = preg_match('/.*video\/(\d{1,})\?title.*/', $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Thanks for that I will also remove the `title` part and just keep the `?` that should be safer if vars are swapped arround.

Comment: `/.*\/(\d+)\?.*/` should be all you need, but seriously, consider using the classic `strpos` I suggested below. It's simple, fast, and actually follows the URI spec, while the regexp here is a bit fragile.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the two explodes? Sure, you can do it with a regular expression. But given the way URLs are defined, I'd first delete everything after the first `?`, then everything before the last `/` in the remainder.

While some consider a regexp elegant here (and in fact, I might even be using it myself), `strpos` and `strrpos` is just as fast and reliable here.

```
$end = strpos($test, "?") - 1;
$sta = strrpos(substr($test, 0, $end), "/") + 1;
$ret = substr($test, $sta, $end);
```

Comment: OK than thanks for the tip. What is the diff. in`strpos` & `strrpos` over `explode`?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php, http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php would love to tell you this.

Comment: `explode` is more expensive, when you are in fact only interested in a single part of the line. Use `strpos` to find the `?`, then `strrpos` to find the last `/`, then `substr` to get exactly the characters you need. Simple and efficient.

Comment: And using regular expressions is even more expensive, as a matter of fact. Plus, they are more prone to error matches.

Answer (score 1):

```
$pattern = '/\<iframe\s+.*src\=\"?[^\"]*player\.vimeo\.com\/video\/([\d]{5,})\??.*\".*\<\/iframe\>/i';

if(preg_match($pattern, $iframe_tag, $result)){
    $vimeo_id = $result[1];
}
```